# Identifying spreadsheet cells where a string appears multiple times using VBA or Google Apps Script

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets, vba

I'd like to highlight cells in which there are repeated words. For example,

A1: Best jackets in town.
A2: Best jackets in in town.
A3: Best Best Jackets in Town.

I'd like to highlight A2 & A3 as the words "in" and "best" are occuring multiple times in them. How do I do this using VBA? 
Would be fine with a Google Apps Script solution too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### No script: conditional formatting

If one takes the position that words are separated only by spaces, and that repetition anywhere in the string is acceptable (i.e., "cry baby cry" also counts as repetition), then a script isn't needed: conditional formatting in Google Sheets can do the job. Apply it with custom formula

```
=len(join(" ", unique(transpose(split(A1, " "))))) < len(A1)
```

where A1 should be replaced with the upper left corner of the range being formatted.

The idea is to split the string by spaces, pick *unique* words with `unique`, and put them together. If the result is shorter than the original, there was some repetition.

#### Google Apps Script solution

Google Apps Script can use any JavaScript regular expression methods, allowing for a wider range of text processing rules.

Version 1: **back-to-back repetition**: "best game in in town" matches but "cry baby cry" does not. This is expressed by the regex

```
\b(\w+)\W+\1\b
```

Version 2: **unrestricted repetition**: both "best game in in town" and "cry baby cry" match. Expressed by the regex

```
\b(\w+)\b.*\b\1\b
```

Any regex you choose goes into `re` variable in the following script, which processes all values in the currently active sheet. It chooses a background for each cell and sets it with `setBackgrounds`.

```
function repeated() {
  var re = /\b(\w+)\W+\1\b/;
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var backgrounds = range.getBackgrounds();
  var values = range.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < values[0].length; j++) {
      backgrounds[i][j] = re.test(values[i][j]) ? "yellow" : "white";
    }
  }
  range.setBackgrounds(backgrounds);
}
```

Comment: I'm new to the apps script and javascript for that matter, what exactly is happening at the line

**_backgrounds[i][j] = re.test(values[i][j]) ? "yellow" : "white"_**

Comment: I use the [test method of a regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) and the result is fed to a [conditional ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator). The outcome is that the background is yellow if the regex matches the cell's content.

Comment: Thank You Soup! That really helps!